# Setting up 2 way binding between parent controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set up a 2 way binding between a parent controller and a directive. This works if I set the scope to '=' and I only use the actual attribute itself. However, if I use this attribute to derive another value, that value does not get updated properly. How can I set it to update as well.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.ctrlVal = 'one';
     $scope.updateDirective = function(){
        $scope.ctrlVal = 'two';
    } 
});

app.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{input}} - {{derived}}</div>',
        scope:{input: '='},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
            switch(scope.input){
                case 'one':
                    scope.derived = '1';
                break;
                case 'two':
                    scope.derived = '2';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

When I trigger the updateDirective function on the controller via ng-click, the {{input}} part gets updated, but not the {{derived}} part

A fiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/m3k2w/8/

EDIT: Updated fiddle showing the answers from below: http://jsfiddle.net/m3k2w/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you aren't responding to changes on `scope.input`.  Your switch statement only runs once, when the `link` function is executed.  You need to `$watch` for changes on `scope.input` and execute your code at that point.

Try this:

```
scope.$watch('input', function() {

    switch(scope.input){
        case 'one':
            scope.derived = '1';
            break;
        case 'two':
            scope.derived = '2';
            break;
    }

});
```

I like to break it out a bit more so it the behaviors are separated... one function is responsible for translating the value and the `$watch` callback is responsible for mutating `scope`.

```
// declare this translation function before you return your directive object
function getDerived(input) { 
    case 'one': return '1';
    case 'two': return '2';
}

scope.$watch('input', function() {
    scope.derived = getDerived(scope.input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working solution :http://jsfiddle.net/m3k2w/9/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.ctrlVal = 'one';
    $scope.updateDirective = function(){
        $scope.ctrlVal = 'two';
    } 
});

app.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{input}} - {{derived}}</div>',
        scope:{input: '='},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
            // add $watch : each time 'input' is updated, the function will be executed
            scope.$watch('input',function(){
                switch(scope.input){
                    case 'one':
                        scope.derived = '1';
                    break;
                    case 'two':
                        scope.derived = '2';
                    break;
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

more infos [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)